# Qlik Sense - Ignoring Filter in AGGR Set Expression

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression, set-analysis

I wanr ro build a KPI for an average value of patients in the selected year - means I want to include the selected year as filter but want to use all 12 months and all quarters:

Avg(Aggr(Count(
{$<Quarter =, Month=> * (<FallBewegungKey = {"=Aggr(Count(ICD), FallBewegungKey) > 0"}> +
<FallBewegungKey = {"=Aggr(Count(Leistungsziffer), FallBewegungKey) > 0"}>)}
DISTINCT Fallnummer), Month))

But still, if I select a month via a table or filter pane, the selection is still applied and the KPI changes accordingly, while it should be ignored.

What am I doing wrong in this place?

Comment: Your selection still applies to the Avg. Add the set analysis on on the Avg, ex: `Avg( {<....>} Aggr(...) )`